# How do I set the SCSS of a single page's tags to transparent in Ionic 2?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I built out a simple, single page application that uses the Cordova CameraPreview plugin to show the Android camera with Ionic components on top. The tutorial I followed used the below code segment to make the background transparent so that you can see the camera. Now I am trying to build on that tutorial and have a single page that is transparent, but the rest of the pages should not be.

```
html, body, ion-app, ion-content, ion-page, .nav-decor {
    background-color: transparent !important; 
}
```

The simple question is: How do I a make the HTML background for one page transparent, but not the others?

This is probably simple, but I am new to Ionic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scss page(lets assume your page name is login),

```
page-login{
    background: transparent !important;
}
```

This will work. However, you will not see any difference if you wrapped some content inside . In such case, you need to give define transparent to

```
.content-md{
    background: transparent !imporant;
}
```